Camunda. BPMN. Finding the proper value from an array variable
At the output of the external task, I have a variable of the “Object” type in the form of a Json-file (the file is attached). It is necessary to look through each "document" array and look at its parameters, pulling out the values ​​of the parameter where the key is equal to "protocol num" for each internal document array and get the output "id" of the document whose "protocol num" value is the largest.
I use Groovy for Camunda scripts.
The Input variable is configured like this:
ArrayList = []
def sampleDocumentFilter = [:]
def sampleDocument = [:]

sampleDocument.sampleIds = [sampleAnalysisRequest.sampleId]
sampleDocumentFilter.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

sampleDocumentFilter.filter = sampleDocument
result = [sampleDocumentFilter]
result

And that is 100% correctly.
Firstly, I tried to get all values, where "key" = "ProtocolNums" (output variable):
def ProtocolNums = []
where:
object.documents.parameters.key = "ProtocolNum"
for (docs in object.documents)
{
   ProtocolNums.add(docs.parameters.value)
}
ProtocolNums

But an incident appears in Camunda - Argument type mismatch (scrin Camunda failure)

Failure


Please don't paste screenshots of code and error messages... Why not just copy them into the question as you did with the code samples

if object.documents is pointing to a list of documents you show in example then approximately this code should find the element with highest ProtocolNum:
def theOne = object.documents.max{
  it.parameters?.find{it.key=='ProtocolNum'}?.value as int 
}
println theOne.id


Hey. tried this.
Camunda error. Type: "ScriptCompilationException"; Message: "Unable to compile script: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script102.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 1, column 34.
def theOne = object.documents.max{
^
1 error
"
